# Is my interpretation of "向右往后勾提。至甲势已背时" correct in the context of Tai Chi?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, literary-chinese

I'm translating a two-person push hands sequence from a Yang-Style Taiji Quan manual.

In the description of the 62nd form, "Right Cloud Hands" (右云手)， there's a sentence that reads: "向右往后勾提。至甲势已背时。”

“甲” in this context translates to "Martial Artist #1", one of the participants in this two-person push hands form.  My current translation of this sentence reads as "Face to the right and shift back, drawing out the force from #1's back until none is left."

Does my translation of "勾提“ make sense in this context, and does my translation generally fit the principles of this Tai Chi form?

Comment: Literal meanings: 勾= hook; 提= lift -- 勾提 = hook and lift

Comment: I have no answer, but I found this, another curriculum: 乙在甲右掌扑来时，右拳变掌，前臂内旋，从甲右臂外向上、向右划弧（拇指向），采拿甲的右腕，并向右侧拨引，同时向右转捶，左手立掌向前按甲的右上臂。眼注视甲的面部。此时乙面向西，甲面向东北。

Comment: So what the total form of this Taiji?  24 ? 42? 85? 103?   My suggestion is : don't translate by words, but by its meaning ( 不要直译, 要意译) .  Because "向右往后勾提。至甲势已背时" is not easy to understand for chinese native speakers and I search this but got not result, in baidu.com, which is a better search engine than google.

Answer (score 4):

first of all

> a two-person push hands sequence

the mentioned verse is of sparring (散手), **not** push hand (推手)

[image]

甲 is the left man, grey cloth; 乙 is the right one, white cloth

> 乙被掤・乘勢含胸拔背・向右轉腰坐腿・右手刁住甲右腕・向右往後勾提・至甲勢已背時・右手按甲右腕・同時左手按擊甲右肩

[乙’s ] right hand stick with 甲’s right wrist (右手刁住甲右腕)

towards 乙’s right and aft [向右往後], connected [hand and wrists] (勾), slightly upward (提); till (至) the moment that 甲’s posture (勢) shows his back (背)

the hidden message is: 乙’s wrist, arm moves according to the turning of waist and shifting centre of gravity (轉腰坐腿)

> as "Face to the right and shift back, drawing out the force from #1's back until none is left."

> Does my translation of "勾提“ make sense in this context

nice try  well, i’m sorry to say, no.

btw, here’s a wordpress page, you may find helpful info:

https://brennantranslation.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/taiji-two-person-sparring-set-taiji-san-shou-dui-da/

have fun :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the link! This'll really help with my translation!